# Can't get Moq to return a value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, moq

I'm using Moq to unit test some of our code which uses Entity Framework. Inside my unit test I have the following code, however when I test it I am unable to get the correct value returned (everything compiles ok, but the result of count is 0 and null is returned). This suggests to me that my Entity object was never added to my mocked repo.

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetEntity_ValidName_EntityReturned()
{
    Entity testEntity = new Entity();
    testEntity.Name = "Test";

    var mockService = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
    mockService.Setup(mock => mock.EntityRepo.Add(testEntity));
    IUnitOfWork testDB = mockService.Object;
    testDB.EntityRepo.Add(testEntity);

    Entity testEntity2 = EntityHelper.getEntity(testDB,testEntity.Name);
    int count = testDB.EntityRepo.Count();

    Assert.AreEqual(testEntity.Name,testEntity2.Name);
}
```

How can I add an Entity? Do I even need to? I've also tried the following which doesn't compile:

```
mockService.Setup(mock => mock.EntityRepo.Add(testEntity)).Returns(testEntity);
```

Ditto for this:

```
mockService.SetupGet(mock => mock.EntityRepo.Add(testEntity)).Returns(testEntity);
```

EDIT: This is the target for the test:

```
public static Entity getEntity(IUnitOfWork database, string entityName)
{
    Entity _entity = database.EntityRepo.Find(x => x.Name.ToLower().Trim() == entityName).FirstOrDefault();
    return _entity;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code that test is targetting? In general you only need to return something you are going to use in the test.

Comment: Sure I'll add it now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the command you need to mock:

```
database.EntityRepo.Find
```

You don't need to worry about mocking the service, just the `IUnitOfWork`
Something like:

```
testDB.Setup(m => m.Find(It.IsAny<object[]>())).Returns(new List<Entity>() entity);
```

**Worked example:**

Because of the double dotting, we need to hang a mock off the `IUnitOfWork` for `EntityRepo`

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetEntity_ValidName_EntityReturned()
{
    Entity testEntity = new Entity();
    testEntity.Name = "Test";

    var mockEntityRepo = new Mock<IRepo>(); // Type of Repo here
    var mockService = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
    mockService.Setup(m => m.EntityRepo).Returns(mockEntityRepo.Object);

    mockEntityRepo.Setup(m => m.Find(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Entity, bool>>>())).Returns(testEntity);

    Entity testEntity2 = EntityHelper.getEntity(mockService.Object, testEntity.Name);
    int count = testDB.EntityRepo.Count();

    Assert.AreEqual(testEntity.Name,testEntity2.Name);
}
```

The mock setup should correspond to the calls made in the method being tested.

Comment: I'm getting an error at m.Find saying that my IUnitOfWork doesn't contain a method definition for 'Find' (apologises if I'm missing something super simple; very new to entity framework & unit testing!)

Comment: No, its my fault i missed the two dots. What is a `EntityRepo`  ?

Comment: Sorry that was my bad, I had mockService.Setup instead of testDB.Setup (although now it is saying that testDB doesn't have a method definition for .Setup)

Comment: @Novastorm that should work, assuming you put your repository type there where I've stuck the comment

Comment: Managed to get the test constructed for the most part however I ran into a couple of problems regarding the m.Find and the Entity at the end of line 57. Rather than trying to explain I have uploaded a screen capture here along with the error messages: http://i.imgur.com/xzGFi36.png

Comment: @Novastorm entity should have been testentity. I've updated my answer. I'll have a look at find in a sec

Comment: @Novastorm I've changed the type on the find too

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time out to help :) I've changed test to testEntity and the original error is still present ( ') expected' )

Comment: Updating the type for the find has given the same error, though it now says "convert from 'System.Predicate<string>'" instead of "convert from 'object[]'"

Comment: @Novastorm sorry, I meant Predicate<Entity> (I was using string in my test app). Bad cut and paste :-\

Comment: Weirdly it is still giving the same error (just now with 'System.Predicate<Entity>'). I took another look at the error and it looks like it expected a bool result so I did this and it seems happy, though I'm unsure if this will return the desired result: m.Find(x => x.Name.Equals(testEntity.Name))

Comment: @Novastorm looking at the screen shot I think it needs to be `mockEntityRepo .Setup(m => m.Find(It.IsAny<Func<Entity, bool>>())).Returns(testEntity);`

Comment: Almost there; that has gotten rid of the bulk of the errors, only these 2 remain at m.Find: http://i.imgur.com/31XnVD0.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100490/discussion-between-novastorm-and-nikolaidante).